# Is elasticsearch multi get api realtime?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is the elasticsearch mget api realtime like the get api? The documentation only says it returns data in similar format to the get api, does not mention if it is also realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `_mget` endpoint is also realtime (by default) but can also be executed in non-realtime if desired.

A quick look at the source code of [`MultiGetRequest.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/ba08313417b96086eea8de9d5a8d8501bf2b9806/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/get/MultiGetRequest.java#L263) reveals that the `realtime` boolean is `true` by default but can also be set to `false` if desired.

Comment: are documents indexed with client.index api accessible realtime? Or only those PUT?

Comment: Yes, they are. Only search is not realtime.